# Call vuex getters from Vue-Router

Tags: reactive-programming, vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

Is it possible to call vuex getters from the router?
I need to check the state of a boolean variable from beforeach hook:

```js
router.beforeEach(function ({ to, next }) {
    if (to.path !== '/login') {
        // return a Promise that resolves to true or false
        return the-needed-variable-from-store;
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

How can I get and check the variable derived from the store?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: just import the store the router file "import store from '../store' " and return the value of store "return store.getters" but if you want to access the value of store in all routes, it is much better to use vue-router-sync package

Answer (score 0):

There was a discussion on this here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync/issues/3#issuecomment-200192468

I was able to access the variable in a fairly ridiculous way:

```
router.beforeEach((transition)=>{
    if(transition.to.auth){
        if(!transition.to.router.app.$store.state.auth.authorized){
            transition.abort()
            router.go({path:"/"})
        }
    }
    transition.next()
});
```

So in your case it might look like `to.router.app.$store.state`